# What is this image blurring, and is it possible to control?

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, browser

I recently noticed this strange behavior in Chrome when increasing and decreasing the size of the zoom and consequently an `img`.

[image: browser blurring]

It might be hard to tell at first but the image on the left is blurred vs the image on the right that is sharp. I took these screenshots from the same image, from the same webpage, in the same browser, at the same size.

The only difference being that, for the image on the right, I scaled my browser zoom up, then down, and took the screenshot before the image had time to 'blur'. The image on the left, is taken a second or two after the zoom in/out commands have finished, and the image gets blurred. As a side note, the same behavior happens when you increase or decrease the rendering size of the `img` by adjusting the `width`. I think it's important to note that the image is huge 1920px and being shrunk down to about 300px.

I prefer the look of a crisp image, vs a blurred one, even if it's at a smaller size. Why does the blurring happen, and is it possible to stop it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering